# Kernel config: Is undefined the same as disabled?

Tags: linux, kernel

Reading the [Debian Kernel Handbook](https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html) I came across the config option `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`.

That option isn't in the official debian 3.2 kernel config, so what I'd like to know:

If a certain option is not in the .config file, does that count as "undefined" and is "undefined" the same as "disabled"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of that config option, "undefined" means "disabled", see the `Makefile`:

```
ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -g
KBUILD_AFLAGS   += -gdwarf-2
endif
```

So, the answer is: **it depends**. There are config options in the `Makefile` with `else`,  and other statements. Such a contant can also have a value that defines a different behavior.

Comment: OMG, should have checked the Makefile prior to posting... Thank you!